# Magento 2 Rest API with C# Restsharp unable to get stock item containing symbols

Tags: apache, rest, mod-rewrite, magento2, restsharp

I have an issue very similar to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296098/unable-to-get-stock-item-via-rest-api. I'm using Restsharp to create a json request to magento 2 Rest api. This works for majority of my stock items but some contain symbols ie #12654 .

For these items Restsharp is returning a Bad request. I'm creating the request as below. #12654 is valid in M2 but in the magento 2 swagger a hash symbol is converted to %23 when the request is executed. Anyone know how to encode the hash symbol properly for the magento api to read it?

```
  private RestClient Client { get; set; }
    private string Token { get; set; }

    public Rest(string magentoUrl, string token)
    {
        Token = token;
        Client = new RestClient(magentoUrl);
    }

    private RestRequest CreateRequest(string endPoint, Method method, string token)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, method);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        return request;
    }

  public void GetSku(string sku)
    {
        var request = CreateRequest("/rest/all/V1/products/" + sku, Method.GET, Token);
        var response = Client.Execute(request);
        //Update Product with current Price & stock level
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            do stuff.
        }
        else
        {
            var tmp = ":( " + response.Content;
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe this could be an apache2 config issue?#

Comment: tried RewriteRule ^/rest/all/V1/products/$1 ^/rest/all/V1/products/$1 [NE] in .htaccess but still get badrequest

Comment: checking the request with var fullUrl = Client.BuildUri(request); it sends correct string including # but still getting bad request.. would this be an apache error? rewrite above doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Looking in the apache log's it looks as though Restsharp is stripping the data from hash symbol onwards 12/Jan/2020:08:05:48 +0000] "GET /rest/all/V1/products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1565 "-" "RestSharp/106.0.0.0"